# chromium browser remotely launched error

Tags: ssh, chromium

I logged into a remote server using the -X option in the ssh command.
After trying to open the chromium browser i get the following error:

> $ chromium-browser
>
> Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
>   [4579:4579:0715/195232:ERROR:url_pattern_set.cc(240)] Invalid url
>   pattern: chrome://print/* libGL error: failed to open drm device: No
>   such file or directory libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
>   [4611:4611:0715/195233:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(340)]
>   InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process
>   gpu-process

Nonetheless I'm able to open the browser and use it.
Any idea what might be causing the problem?

**NOTE**

I thought the problem could have been the missing module `canberra-gtk-module`, but after following the instructions [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/gtk-message-failed-to-load-module-canberra-gtk-module-936168/) (install the module with `sudo apt-get install canberra-gtk3-module`) nothing changed.

Comment: I've always seen these as harmless errors/warnings, but I'm interested to see if I'm wrong about that.  Do you get the same errors if you run `chromium-browser` from your local terminal?

Comment: @earthmeLon - It doesn't, but shows this message instead: `ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.`. But why would it matter at all? Local and remote are two completely different systems.

Comment: You're right, however, I am trying to show you that programs throw errors such as these to STOUT all the time, and are typically harmless.  You normally do not see these when launching a program, vs running it from the command line.  I wanted to *expose* these warnings/errors to you to see if there is actually an issue.

Comment: @earthmeLon - i see! So should I just ignore them? :)

Comment: I've seen your first example of errors, but never had the program show any issues or crash.  Personally, I've always ignored them, but I'm here just in case someone steps in and shows us a solution. :D